# Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

I have a SharePoint environment, but my problem is related to DB as I couldn't solve it in SharePoint ways.

I have a database that suddenly stopped working. It's appearing in SQL management studio, but without the + sign. If I right click on it to see the tasks, they're disabled.

I have full control over the server as am the one who installed SQL and Windows. Any idea how to solve this.

Comment: Seems either the database is suspect, or missing database or log files. Run`sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'db_name'` where db_name is database name and add the message in question

Comment: Where to run this from? Please tell me step by step

Comment: I ran this in SS management studio as a query, and I got a long list

Comment: It has 3 log messages repeated over and over, saying there's an error, then setting database option MULTI_USEr to ON, then starting up, then error again, what's going on?

Comment: Please read the complete response, paste the output of the errorlog in the question. If it is too big add it on shared drive and paste link here so that we can see

Comment: MS has a "Solving SQL Server Connectivity issues walkthrough" that they published a little while back to help with connection problems.  You could give it a shot.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2017/01/29/solving-sql-connectivity-issues-a-new-guided-walk-through-just-got-published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## sp_readerrorlog

As pointed out already by @Shanky read the error log (ERRORLOG) by setting off the sp_readerrorlog command:

```
sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'<your_DB>'
```

You could also use the official xp_readerrorlog procedure with the same parameters:

```
xp_readerrorlog 0,1,'<your_DB>'
```

xp_readerrorlog is the underlying extended stored procedure for the sp_readerrorlog stored procedure which is explained here: [SQL Internals : Useful Parameters for xp_readerrorlog](https://sqlserver-help.com/2014/12/10/sql-internals-useful-parameters-for-xp_readerrorlog/)

## Read ERRORLOG directly

If you are unable to read the ERRORLOG with the stored procedures, then manually read the ERRORLOG files (ERRORLOG.*) to find any errors.

#### Querying Registry to find location

If you can't find the location of the ERRORLOG file, then retrieve the path from the registry:

```
DECLARE @regout VARCHAR(255)  
exec xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\Parameters', 'SQLArg1', @regout OUTPUT  
SELECT @regout
```

Don't forget to replace `MSSQLSERVER` with your **instance name** if you are using a different instance than the default instance (...\MSSQL11.**MSSQLSERVER**\...).

## Query SQL Server directly

SQL Server itself stores some basic information about the status of the databases in `sys.databases`:

```
select name, state_desc from sys.databases
```

You should get an output similar to the following:

```
name    state_desc
master  ONLINE
tempdb  ONLINE
model   ONLINE
msdb    ONLINE
<your_DB>   ONLINE
```

## Permissions

If your database `<your_DB>` is online, then you possibly don't have adequate permissions to read the database. Change your user's permissions.

Once you have found more information you will possibly be able to pinpoint the issue.